# Centering a form, but maintaining alignment of its contents

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, margin

I have a three-column page. Each column is a div with the following styles:

```
.Row1 {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0.5%;
    width:31.5%;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="Row1">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <br />
    <form>
        Form stuff goes here
    </form>
</div>
```

My form consists of nothing more than a text field, a few radio buttons, and a submit button. Problem is, putting the form into the above code will give me a centered form, with the text field, radio buttons, and submit button also aligned in the center.

What I am trying to do is to just center the form itself (as a container), but keep everything aligned to the left.

I have tried wrapping the form in a div that is text-aligned centrally, and the form style set to left align, but that didnt work. The auto margin thing didn't work, either, whether it was on the wrapping div, or on the form, without the wrapping div (that is, an extra div. the Row1 div always remains).

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/pJwqe/

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), using the auto margin thing and filling in some sample form controls, and someone will be able to show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: I would, if I could get it to load fully. Not sure why it just remains stuck half way.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` is not a property to 'align' divs or forms; instead, as it says, it aligns text.
If you want to center a block-level element, you'll have to use margin. The default way to center a single element with margin is to set it , for example for a top-level container, to `margin: 0px auto 0px;`.

If you want a lay-out with 3 columns, I'd rather think you'd want something like [this](http://jsbin.com/esotic/4/edit).
You can style the margins of your divs by setting `margin-left` or `margin-right`, then style the first/last element with advanced selectors (so you don't have a margin-left for your first element, or a margin-right for your last).

As you can see, the forms are now centered, but their content is not. (You need to give your forms a width, else they will fill the containing block by default if they have content).

NB: It might be relevant in the rest of your code, but in this test-case `vertical-align` does nothing.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/esotic/7
If you look at it here, the form container is centered, but the inputs are still to the left. I want them in the center, but with their left sides all aligned (rather than their center points being aligned). I'm not sure if that even made sense.

Comment: Soz bro, but that doesn't make sense. You can't center two different-length blocks at their left-most point, unless you re-invent some kind of wicked mathemathics system. You can however put an 'indent' that is the same for all. Here is an updated example: http://jsbin.com/esotic/10/edit (only applied to middle form). Do `input {margin-left: [formwidth(100%)-longestInputWidth(80%)]/2(=10%)}`. That's the closest you can get to what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pJwqe/5/) will work for you. I have done the following changes in your css

```
.midAlign form {
border: 1px solid #C2C3C0;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 155px;
}
```